# Autofac - Resolve Generics by base class

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a mapping hierarchy of interfaces/classes that use generics constrained by a base class and I am trying to resolve them to their derived classes using the base classes. I am wondering if Autofac can resolve this in a better way than I am currently doing it.

Taking the following structure:

```
public interface IMapper<T1, T2> 
    where T1 : FooBase
    where T2 : BarBase
{
    T1 Map(T2 source);
}


public class FooBarMapper : IMapper<Foo, Bar>
{
    public Foo Map(Bar source)
    {
        return new Foo
        {
            blahblah = source.xyz
        };
    }
}
```

Next, I have a "To" extension method on "Foo" which references the base types, but I want to resolve it to a proper type. I currently resolve like this:

```
public static TDest To<TDest>(this BarBase o) where TDest : FooBase
{
    var genericMapper = typeof(IMapper<,>).MakeGenericType(o.GetType(), typeof(TDest));
    object mapper = IocProxy.Container.Resolve(genericMapper);

    //... etc
}
```

This resolves fine... but mapper is just an object. So I'd have to use reflection to hit the "Map" method. Which I'd rather avoid doing. Can autofac do this in a better way so that I end up with an IMapper as opposed to an object? For example, I'd prefer to do something like this, but autofac obviously doesn't resolve it:

```
var mapper = IocProxy.Container.Resolve<IMapper<FooBase, TDest>>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is a bit ugly. Because you can't create the "To" extension method with 1 generic, you have to make the code look ugly so that it can infer both types. Like this:

```
public static TDest To<TDest,TSource>(this TSource o) where TDest : new()
{
    var mapper = IocProxy.Container.Resolve<IMapper<TSource, TDest>>();
    return mapper.Map(o);
}
```

Somewhere deeper down we get this ugly call:

```
var b = a.To<Bar,Foo>(); //<-- to convert it to "Bar" we need to specify both generics
```

Yes, ugly! Who really knows what's getting mapped to what here! Unless you explicitly specify the type, but you know how var crazy some people have gone these days.

Anyway, as I don't like this I developed a workaround to improve readability. Firstly, I created a Map class to wrap my object (and my "To" function). This is an extra step, but acts as a nice intermediary for helping autofac resolve the generics correctly:

```
public class Map<TSource> where TSource : new()
{
    public TSource Object { get; set; }
    public Map(TSource o)
    {
        Object = o;
    }

    public TDest To<TDest>()
    {
        var mapper = IocProxy.Container.Resolve<IMapper<TSource, TDest>>();
        return mapper.Map(Object);
    }
}
```

And then a slightly different generic extension method to get the Mapper back (and get the code into the style I wanted):

```
public static Map<TDest> Map<TDest>(this TDest o) where TDest : new()
{
    return new Map<TDest>(o);
}
```

This does slightly change how I wanted to call it, but it reads equally as well.

So rather than this:

```
foo.To<Bar, Foo>();
```

The code looks like this

```
foo.Map().To<Bar>()
```

You could even extend it further and add and interface to the Map class and get Autofac to resolve it, but I guess it depends on how often you are spinning up mappers. And in the end the performance gain is probably negligible.